# Google Calendar api fetching events anytime after privilateges

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am working with Google Calendar api and want to fetch the events of the calendar.
What i am trying to do is Firstly get the privileges from the user then after that i would not need to ask him again and again for privileges. I should be able to fetch his events anytime.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? And in which language are you developing? For getting the privileges use OAuth https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: Hi Edwin , I am using PHP and I am trying to fetch events of a user from Google Calendar. What i have done so far is got authorization from the user and got fetched the events but problem is i want the authorization only once from user and Google calendar api will give me a token or like that so that i can fetch the events for future purposes. I have read this whole section : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

Comment: i got it know google gives me a token name nextSyncToken by that i fetch events in future . but i dont know how to use next nextSyncToken

Comment: When requesting the token you need to specify access_type=offline.
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline You will get a refresh token, which can be used to obtain new access tokens, without user consent.

Comment: Thanks edwin... havnt tested yet but hope so its gonna work for me.